# Start Google Map Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

hi i wanted to make a button which is the button will start google map intent
with my current location and destination location

how to make a google map automaticlly detect my location and destination longitude and lat?
where i put that longi and lat?

i want that map directly draw the direction to destination

```
     final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
+ "saddr="+ current_lat+","+current_longi + "&daddr="+dest_address ));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(intent);
```

alr tried this code but not working

Comment: whats the code for current_lat and current_longi?

Comment: i want to try that google map detect my location and make direction to latitude and longitue

Comment: If you want to google search your position delete the saddr (start address), and left just left the destination address: &daddr="+targetLat+","+targetLang 

By this way google maps start tracking your position to trace the rout... Too you can to set de saddr, for that you should have and gps roadcastrecevier nd catch your lat&lng, setting these position to the saddr...

Answer (score 5):

Try using one of these with the View intent:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

Something like:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(<ONE OF THE ABOVE STRINGS>);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+currentLattitude+","+currentLongitude+"&daddr="+targetLat+","+targetLang+"&mode=driving";
```

it should work.

Comment: so i put on targetLat like this 110.39066791534424  ?

Comment: if this is the lat coordinate of your desired destination location.

Comment: Intent local = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr=yourlatlng"));
           startActivity(localIntent);
 this one works

Comment: well I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=srcLatitude,srcLongitude&daddr=destLatitude,destLongitude"));
startActivity(intent);


// srcLongitude/Latitude = current Location`s longitude/latitude

// destLongitude/Latitude = Destination Location`s longitude/latitude
```